# css: center a group of objects that are evenly distributed within that group

Tags: html, css, flexbox, stylus

I have a bunch of divs within a container that I want to distribute evenly horizontally:

`[container [obj1] [obj2] [obj3] [obj4] ]`

but I also want the container to be centered in the page

right now my css (stylus) code for the container looks like:

```
@media( min-width: 900px ) {
                display: flex;
                width: 830px;
                margin 0 auto;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
```

which is resulting in some weird margins and the container not being centered in the page. Is this because of the way that I'm using the `display:flex` and 'justify-content` fields?

Comment: Could you please add a working example that shows the weird margins?

Comment: Your approach looks good IMO. Just add a colon after `margin`.

Comment: @jfeferman what's the best way to transmit that? something like a codepen might not best communicate the rendering issues I'm having specifically.

Comment: You can edit your question and incude a code snippet. Just press the <> code button in the editor.

Comment: what I'm finding is that, when I set the width manually, it adds correct margins on both sides but the block is rendered with a margin that is too wide, and the entire block is indented to the left off the width of the page. if I leave that manual width out, it centers on the page with no margins on either side.

Comment: the question does have a code snippet, do you need the css for the containing divs as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the `.container`, you could again add `display: flex` on its parent and use `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` to center the container as shown below:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 70%;
  height: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the following example with a `450px` container. Using `justify-content:space-between` correctly provides even spacing between `div` elements, as you propose.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>small</div>
  <div>very large content</div>
</div>
```

Now, say you wish to expand each `div` to take up all remaining space and also make the `div` elements evenly distributed. Use `flex-grow:1` on child `div` elements to make them take the remaining space. Add `width:calc(100%/3)` to size them evenly.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 4px;
  flex-grow:1;
  width:calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>small</div>
  <div>very large content</div>
</div>
```

Finally, to make that work within a media query, you need to adjust your css as follows:

```css
@media( min-width: 450px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .container div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 4px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: calc(100%/3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>small</div>
  <div>very large content</div>
</div>
```